# Why do atoms stay nearer to each other even when delocalized electron moves away

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

When the delocalized electron moves from between two atoms to other then why yet the measurement of distance between those older two atoms is less than normal single bond.

Comment: Under what circumstances? Crystal bonding? Molecular bonding? Unclear.

Comment: Molecular bonding

Answer (score 1):

There is a significant quantum probability a delocalized electron is there, what in average attracts atoms together, compared to the state there was no such an electron.

E.g. for benzene, the distance is shorter than for a single bond, but longer than for a double bond, being effectively 1.5 bond.

Comment: Poutnik can you elaborate

Comment: Well, elaboration is expected for the question in the first place in this site.. The question could be closed for low effort of the OP.

Comment: I meant that there are delocalized electrons in benzene ring. Those electrons travel throughout the ring. So when one such electron moves away from a position which was in between of two atoms then after that electron going away why yet the atoms are close to each other?  They have nothing to share now until another delocalized electron comes in then why they still stay nearer even though no electron between them for pi bonding

Comment: If you were just 1 minute thinking about any analogy of classical mechanics, you would not ask.